# Revolution Slider: YouTube API Untrusted Origin, but only on one server

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, revolution-slider

I'm developing a WordPress site using the [Revolution Slider](http://revolution.themepunch.com/) with a YouTube video which suposed to autoplay and slide after the video is finished. I'm testing the site with the exact same setup und 3 environments: local, private dev server and client's server. Local and dev are working fine, client's server does show the video, but doesn't get the autoplay nor the slide at the end.

I'm wondering that the console on the client server is saying this:

> Untrusted origin: www.clientsdomain.com … www-embed-player.js:165

This only shows up on their server, the other environments are working fine. And this error seems to cause the problem with the autoplay etc. This message shows up continuously every 0.5 seconds.

**working:**

> www.client.local
>
> client.mydevserver.com

**not working:**

> www.client.com

**Update**

The HTML output of the slide (output by the plugin - the last 2 lines probably cause the error):

```
<div class="tp-caption tp-fade fullscreenvideo tp-videolayer start" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-speed="300" data-start="500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-ytid="7YtvsxB9xQY" data-videowidth="100%" data-videoheight="100%" data-videoattributes="version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;showinfo=0;;origin=http://www.clientsdomain.com;" data-videorate="1" data-videocontrols="controls" data-dottedoverlay="threexthree" data-forcecover="1" data-aspectratio="16:9" data-endspeed="300" data-autoplay="true" data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="true" data-nextslideatend="true" style="z-index: 5; width: 1524px; height: 847px; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);">     
    <iframe style="display: block; width: 1642px; height: 912px; transform-style: preserve-3d; z-index: 0; visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7YtvsxB9xQY?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;showinfo=0;;origin=http://www.clientsdomain.com;" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe52739" class="HasListener"></iframe>
</div>
```

The console output:

```
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
clobbering cookies for Location
clobbering cookies for Location
clobbering cookies for Location
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
clobbering cookies for Location
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1515857171.1432459119; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 May 2017 09:18:39 GMT; domain=twinesocial.com;
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1515857171.1432459119; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 May 2017 09:18:39 GMT; domain=apps.twinesocial.com;
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1515857171.1432459119; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 May 2017 09:18:39 GMT; 
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: fbm_130316653831265=; expires=Wed, 04 Feb 2004 08:00:00 GMT;
clobbering cookie: fbm_130316653831265=; expires=Wed, 04 Feb 2004 08:00:00 GMT;domain=apps.twinesocial.com;
clobbering cookie: fbm_130316653831265=base_domain=true; expires=Tue, 24 May 2016 09:18:39 GMT; path=/; domain=true
Call from classic.js
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1515857171.1432459119; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 May 2017 09:18:39 GMT; domain=twinesocial.com;
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1515857171.1432459119; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 May 2017 09:18:39 GMT; domain=apps.twinesocial.com;
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1515857171.1432459119; path=/; expires=Tue, 23 May 2017 09:18:39 GMT; 
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookies for Location
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookies for Location
clobbering cookie getter
clobbering cookie: remote_sid=;domain=youtube.com;path=/;expires=Sat, 31 Jan 1970 23:00:00 GMT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Untrusted origin: http://www.clientsdomain.de
Untrusted origin: http://www.clientsdomain.de
```

You can find a [working example here](http://previous.themepunch.com/revolution4-jquery/liveguide/07.Sample-Videos.html) (Slide 2, Vimeo, though).

My (hopefully not stupid) question is: Could this problem be domain name related? The setups are identical on all three envs and all domains are non-ssl.

Thank you!

Comment: can you plz show dev url..

Comment: Unfortunately not because it's a campaign website and the campaign has not been launched yet.

Comment: can you post code and html here?

Comment: @MukeshPanchal I updated the thread. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an ad blocker? I turned off my ad blocker, Privacy Badger, because I was experiencing the same weird clobbering cookies and it fixed the console errors.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something to do with the `origin` parameter, try removing it altogether, it is optional and protects against malicious third-party JavaScript. If you are getting this parameter wrong, the video may not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as-designed. We ignore messages from untrusted sources for security reasons, and we log these warnings so clients are aware that we're ignoring the events. There is no way to disable.